# YouTube Data API V3 search list returns different results than youtube search

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube data api v3 to get the most viewed videos for a channel. This other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655324/get-the-most-viewed-videos-from-a-channel-and-get-a-channels-featured-video-usi) said the best way to do this is "search->list with specifying the channelId and order = viewcount".

What I've found is this result sometimes differs from what I see by directly going to a YouTube channel.

For a specific example, I'm looking at this channel: 
https://www.youtube.com/user/TheGIIF/videos

It has 3 videos.

Compare that with the following request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=viewCount&part=id&channelId=UCKvRfU5Yaf8XijZPXFJfmlg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This returns the following json:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"k1sYjErg4tK7WaQQxvJkW5fVrfg/xXXGtXCJVmIX8cvSbV7aTD43t0g\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 2,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"k1sYjErg4tK7WaQQxvJkW5fVrfg/pX-Ao3RW_w2XWZZfiA3_50lj7Ks\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCKvRfU5Yaf8XijZPXFJfmlg"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"k1sYjErg4tK7WaQQxvJkW5fVrfg/5uoVIdj1bFGaDCWnwAVwP1RwTyI\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "EsX40Bu84O0"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

So only one available video. Why the discrepancy?

And, not sure if this is just coincidental, but if I search the channel name within the channel:
https://www.youtube.com/user/TheGIIF/search?query=thegiif

I only get back 1 video, the same video as the json response above.